# How to Update Counter in ElasticSearch from Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working on a Spark Structured Streaming project, the goal is to **upsert** user activity logs to ElasticSearch.

**The Problem**:

1. When the `user_id` shows for the first time in last 8 hours, create a new entry in ElasticSearch, and set `counter` in the document to 1;
2. If there are more activities (logs) of the same user in last 8 hours, update `counter` field, add number of activities to its value, and lastly, update `update_time` field.

Setting `"es.mapping.id" -> "user_id"` and `"es.write.operation" -> "upsert"` is as far as I can go, but I cannot update the counter and time when updating. Maybe `es.update.script.inline` would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after reading [ES Scripted Updates document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates), here's a simple solution to **update `counter`** using painless inline-scripting.

So, the key is to use painless script `ctx._source.counter += params.counter`, which `counter` represent my DataFrame column `'counter`, that should be aggregated earlier.

After all, I end up like this:

```
val esOptions = Map(
   "es.write.operation"      -> "upsert"
  ,"es.mapping.id"           -> "user_id"
  ,"es.update.script.lang"   -> "painless"
  ,"es.update.script.inline" -> "ctx._source.counter += params.counter"
  ,"es.update.script.params" -> "counter:counter"

df.writeStream.options(esOptions)
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .start("user_activity/log")
```

Again, this only solves counter update. Will append the way to update `update_time` field later as I nail it.